# Что такое «вальс-казак»? Почему «вальс-казак» пишется через дефис? Какова этимология?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, значение-слов

> *Дуняша бегала взад и вперед как угорелая и то и дело хлопала дверями; а Петр даже в третьем часу ночи все еще пытался сыграть на гитаре **вальс-казак**.*
> И. С. Тургенев, «Отцы и дети».

---

**Что за музыку представляет из себя «вальс-казак»?**

Если он пытался сыграть на гитаре вальс-казак, то значит, существует какая-то определённая музыка этого вальса.
Что именно это за музыка? Есть какой-то композитор или это народная музыка?

---

**Какова этимология «вальс-казак»? Связно ли название с казаками?**

Согласно [Исторического словаря галлицизмов русского языка Епишкина Н. И.](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/8587/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA):

> ВАЛЬС-КАЗАК valse casaque. устар...

Значит, «казак» — «casaque» взято из французского.

На французском «казаки» будет «casaques». Казачий вальс? Однако казаки известны как воины, и трудно представить их танцующими вальс.

Кроме того, казаки — это не французское явление, и не понятно, как такое название танца могло возникнуть во Франции, а потом быть заимствованным в русский язык.

**Обновление:**
«Казаки» будет «cOsaques». «Сasaque» — это дорожный плащ с широкими рукавами. Вальс в дорожнем плаще?

---

**Почему «вальс-казак» пишется через дефис?**

> 2. если в сочетании двух нарицательных существительных первое обозначает родовое понятие, а второе — видовое: цветок хризантема, дерево эвкалипт, гриб подосиновик, птица зяблик, попугай какаду, обезьяна макака, краска серебрянка, газ углерод, нитки мулине, ткань нейлон, леденцы монпансье, суп харчо. 
>     
>     Но если такое сочетание образует сложный научный термин (вторая часть не всегда служит самостоятельным видовым обозначением), название специальности и т. п., то дефис пишется: заяц-русак, птица-лира, ястреб-тетеревятник, жук-олень, жук-носорог, жук-плавунец, рак-богомол, рак-отшельник, мышь-полёвка, бабочка-капустница, врач-терапевт, слесарь-инструментальщик, преподаватель-математик, химик-органик, художник-пейзажист, монах-доминиканец; 
>     
>     [ [Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация. Д. Э. Розенталь.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111) ]

Исходя из правила, должно писаться без дефиса «вальс казак».

Однако в правиле есть оговорка: «Но если такое сочетание образует сложный научный термин (вторая часть не всегда служит самостоятельным видовым обозначением)…».

Можно ли считать «вальс-казак» сложным научным термином?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Родовое и видовое понятие» и научные термины тут ни при чём: транслитерации иностранных словосочетаний в русском языке принято передавать через дефис, хотя бы его в языке-источнике и не было. Вот, например, передача французского же fin de siècle у Бродского:

> ...и рука выпускает пустой графин.
>
> Однако в дверях не священник и не раввин,
>
> но эра по кличке **фин-**

> **де-сьекль**. Модно все черное: сорочка, чулки, белье.
>
> Когда в результате вы все это с нее
>
> стаскиваете, жилье

> озаряется светом примерно в тридцать ватт,
>
> но с уст вместо радостного «виват!»
>
> срывается «виноват».

«Если он пытался сыграть на гитаре вальс-казак, то значит, существует
какая-то определённая музыка этого вальса. Что именно это за музыка?
Есть какой-то композитор или это народная музыка?»

Не музыка: там несколько иной *ритм*, чем в классическом или, как тогда выражались, в «обыкновенном» вальсе. Классический вальс, как известно, танцуют на «раз-два-три», а с «казаком» дело обстоит сложнее:

> Вальс-казак считается раз-два, раз-два-три, первые два раза считаются медленно, но последние три очень скоро; первые два раза принадлежат к па-де-баску, а последние три к пристукиванию ногами.
>
> http://historicaldance.spb.ru/index/articles/books/aid/66

По ссылке можно прочесть и как выглядел этот па-де-баск, Pas de Basque, «баскский шаг».

«Казачий вальс? Однако казаки известны как воины, и трудно представить их танцующими вальс» — зря: казаки и веселиться умели. И танцевать — в том числе вальс.

> В начале XX в. в среде молодежи популярными стали балы – молодёжные вечера. Обычно для них снимали просторную комнату. На балы попадали только
> по приглашениям, которые могли быть устными или письменными. Из музыкальных инструментов, сопровождавших балы, были гармонь, скрипка, бубен. Чаще других танцевали «барыню», вальс, «парочку», то есть что-то вроде «русской».
>
> https://minfo.rk.gov.ru/uploads/txteditor/minfo/attachments//d4/1d/8c/d98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e/phpgMI2aB_b2019-3.pdf

«Кроме того, казаки — это не французское явление, и не понятно, как такое название танца могло возникнуть во Франции, а потом быть заимствованным в русский язык.

**Обновление:** «Казаки» будет «cOsaques». «Сasaque» — это дорожный плащ с широкими рукавами. Вальс в дорожнем плаще?» — французское называние вальсу вполне могли дать и в России. Это, кстати, объясняло бы **а** вместо **о**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А где это правило можно почитать?

Comment: Я проголосовал за ответ.

Comment: «А где это правило можно почитать?» — в таком изложении, где бы делался упор именно на транслитерацию кириллицей латиничных словосочетаний — или сложных слов, как «веб-сайт» (website), — оно мне не попадалось, но на практике такое было и есть в порядке вещей: «интернет-кафе», «яхт-клуб», «креп-жоржет»... да, в конце концов, «Санкт-Петербург»!

Comment: А вообще сюда более-менее подходит такое правило: «В именах существительных пишется ДЕФИС в следующих случаях: • сложные существительные без соединительной гласной, каждая часть которых может употребляться как самостоятельное слово. Примеры: диван-кровать, купля-продажа, стоп-кран и др. — https://krasnozerskaya-nov.ru/defis-v-sushchestvitelnykh-rozental/»

Comment: Да, вероятно, речь идёт не об определённой музыке, а о ритме. Любая музыка с таким ритмом может считаться этим вальсом.

Comment: «Сasaque» не имеет прямого отношения к казакам. Казаки пишутся через «o»: «cosaques». «Сasaque» — это вид одежды. Скорее всего, этот вид вальса танцевали изначально в определённый одежде. Вы, вероятно, правы, что это транслитерация, хотя транслитерация «valse», должна быть «вальсе», а не «вальс».

Comment: Я подожду, может, кто-то что-то ещё напишет. Если нет, приму ваш ответ.

Comment: Я дописал к своему ответу, что казаки тоже танцевали вальс, там есть ссылка на книгу. Книга вообще интересная, и помимо этой инфы.

Comment: «"Сasaque" не имеет прямого отношения к казакам. Казаки пишутся через «o»: «cosaques». «Сasaque» — это вид одежды. Скорее всего, этот вид вальса танцевали изначально в определённый одежде» — я в ответе и об этом дописал: французское название вальсу вполне могли дать и в России, отсюда и «сasaque» вместо «cosaque». «Транслитерация «valse», должна быть «вальсе», а не «вальс»» — ну, все более-менее интеллигентные люди тогда знали, что конечное «e» во французском произносится только в стихах классического метра, — впрочем, другого метра тогда и не было.

Comment: _«…ну, все более-менее интеллигентные люди тогда знали, что конечное „e“ во французском произносится только в стихах классического метра…»_ Я, чесно сказать, не специалист в произношении во Французском языке. В транскрипции слова «valse» нет на конце «e». Google Translate, однако, одно слово «valse» читает без «e», а словосочетание «valse casaque» читает «valse» на конце с «e».

Comment: _«…французское называние вальсу вполне могли дать и в России…»_ Я привёл ссылку на словарь галлицизмов, а галлицизм — это заимствование из французского языка.

Comment: «Google Translate, однако, одно слово «valse» читает без «e», а словосочетание «valse casaque» читает с «valse»» — хм, действительно читает! Странно... Может, там сидит кто-то нетвёрдый в языке?

Comment: «Галлицизм — это заимствование из французского языка» — не совсем. «Галлици́зм (от лат. Gallicus «галльский», фр. gallicisme) — слово или выражение, заимствованное из ИЛИ ПРОИСХОДЯЩЕЕ ОТ французского языка» — https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC